# Is it possible to recursively create folders using a shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to recursively create levels of directories like
`/folder1/folder2/folder3`

I'm trying `mkdir folder1/folder2/folder3`, but it doesn't work. How can I do it?

Comment: When getting errors with tools like `mkdir`, it's always a good idea to try `mkdir --help` or `man mkdir`.

Answer (score 91, accepted):

You should pass the `-p` parameter to `mkdir` so it will create all the subfolders.
So following your example:

```
mkdir -p folder1/folder2/folder3
```

Comment: what does p stand for?

Comment: From mkdir --help: -p, --parents     no error if existing, make parent directories as needed

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to add -Z to make sure the security context is that of the current directory while you're at it:

mkdir -p -Z dir1/dir2/dir3/dir4

assuming that's what you want and you want to avoid having to do a bunch of chown'ing and chmod'ing later.